# Is there a word for a typo?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, word-request, spelling, typography

Yesterday in [our chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36130/conloqvivm) it turned out that we didn't know a Latin word for a typo(graphical error).
For example, I typed *lingarum* instead of *linguarum*.
What would be a Latin word to describe a mistyped word?
Did the Romans have a word for it?
Perhaps something like *error stili* would work, but I have failed to find any classical attestations.
I am sure the phenomenon itself existed in Rome, an people who have studied inscriptions have told me that it is not rare to find misinscribed words — if that is a word.

Comment: Isn't it `lapsus (plumæ/calami)`?

Comment: @user28434 I don't know. If you do, please write it as an answer!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## 1. Mendum

***Mendum*** corresponds exactly to this sense:

> Gaffiot
>   mendum,¹⁴ ī, n., faute, erreur [dans un texte]mendum,¹⁴ ī, n., faute, erreur [dans un texte] :  ; Att. 13, 23, 2
>
> Lewis&Short
>   a fault, error, blunder in writing (class.).

**Examples**:

- *quod **mendum** ista litura correxit?*, Cic. Verr. 2, 2, 104
- *tantum librariorum **menda** tolluntur*, Cic, Att., 13, 23, 2: *

**Mendum typographicum**

According to *A Copious and Critical English-Latin Lexicon*, article « [PRESS](https://books.google.fr/books?id=bIVBAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA527) », a *mendum typographicum* means more precisely a typo where a wrong letter is used (in French, *une coquille*). There are many attestations of it in modern Latin:

- 1710, *Bibliothèque choisie, pour servir de suite à la Bibliothèque universelle*, Le Clerc, p.99: *Epistulam ad Titum fuisse scriptum anno CXCII est manifestum **mendum typographicum**, vel **lapsus calami**, qui non debuerat transire in Editionem Amsterlodamensem.*
- [Many examples on Gallica](http://gallica.bnf.fr/services/engine/search/sru?operation=searchRetrieve&version=1.2&query=%28gallica%20adj%20%22Mendum%20typographicum%22%29&suggest=0)
- …

## 2. Error seu erratum

More simply, the words ***error*** or ***erratum*** can also be used with the meaning of a *typo*.

- Cic, Att., 6, 1, 17 : *At me hercule ego, cum in turma inauratarum equestrium quas hic Metellus in Capitolio posuit animadvertissem in Serapionis subscriptione Africani imaginem, **erratum** fabrile putavi, nunc video Metelli.*
- Quint., Inst., I, 47 : *Pronomen quoque genus numerum casus habet, quae omnia recipiunt huius modi **errorem**.*

**Error typographicum seu typographicus**

It can have the more precise sens of a typo where a wrong word is put (*un bourdon* in French).

- *A Copious and Critical English-Latin Lexicon*, article « [PRESS](https://books.google.fr/books?id=bIVBAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA527) »
- *Deutsch-Lateinisches Wörterbuch* von C. L. Bauer, article « [FEHLER](https://books.google.fr/books?id=O_JPAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA498) »
- *Lateinisch-deutsches und deutsch-lateinisches Schul-worterbuch* von C. F. Ingerslev, article « [DRUCKFEHLER](https://books.google.fr/books?id=7FdGAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA144) »

**Examples for error typographicum/s**:

- 1618, *Romanae correctionis in Latinis Bibliis editionis vulgatae*, Franciscus Lucas: *ISAIAS v.20: (…) Vix dubito quin sit hic error typographicus in editione Romana etc.*
- [Many examples on Google Books](https://www.google.fr/search?hl=fr&dcr=0&tbm=bks&q=%22Error+typographicum%22&oq=%22Error+typographicum%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...4681.6169.0.6333.2.2.0.0.0.0.148.148.0j1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0.0ycgh)
- …

## 3. Vitium

- Quint. Inst., I, 5, 5: *Sed quia interim excusantur haec **vitia** aut consuetudine aut auctoritate aut vetustate aut denique vicinitate virtutum (nam saepe a figuris ea separare difficile est): ne qua tam lubrica observatio fallat, acriter se in illud tenue discrimen grammaticus intendat, de quo nos latius ibi loquemur ubi de figuris orationis tractandum erit.*

**Vitium typographicum**

It can have the more precise sense of a blunder that destroys the sense of the text (*un bourdon* in French, or *un mastic*).

- *A Copious and Critical English-Latin Lexicon*, article « [PRESS](https://books.google.fr/books?id=bIVBAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA527) »

Comment: "worterbuch" is also a typo. Yours.