# Emeo – possibly misspelled word

Tags: vocabulary, spelling

What does word *emeo* mean? 
As in:

> "Heri, ad tabernam eō. In tabernā sunt trēs rēs quārum amō duas sōleās et unam mensam. Habeō trēs denariōs, sīc ego **emeō** mensam sōlum quod sum nōn dīvīnitās"

taken from [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Latin/Lesson_6-Irregular_Verbs), emphasis by myself.

I have not found this word in wiktionary.

It has been suggested by Joonas Ilmavirta in chat that it is in fact misspelled word.

What would be a probable right word then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe it is supposed to be *emo*, "I buy".
This would make sense in the context.
I don't know whether it was a [typing error](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5187/79) or whether the author mistook *emere* for an irregular verb of some kind.
There is also a verb *emeare* (from *e* and *meare*), but it seems inappropriate here.

An excellent tool for analyzing passages like this, when they are correctly spelled, is [this word study tool](http://latinlexicon.org/word_study_tool.php) that gives you (simplified) Lewis & Short entries for each word.
Just copy your little story into the box and click "Search".

The rest is more of a personal opinion on the exercise, and is to be taken with a grain of salt.
The Latin text feels unnatural to me, making me suspicious of the quality of the WikiBook.
There is a banner saying "This page may need to be reviewed for quality." at the top of the page, and such a review is in order.
A couple of things stick out:

- The word order is unusual.
- Misspelled *emo* as *emeo*.
- The last word should presumably be *di(ve)s* (rich), not *divinitas* (divinity).
- The second sentence feels weird: *In tabernā sunt trēs rēs quārum amō duas sōleās et unam mensam.* I would recommend against phrasing "there are three things" as *sunt tres res*. The word *res* is not exactly like the English "thing". In this context, I would replace it with *merx* (merchandise). Also *quārum amō* sounds suspicious; I would much rather say something like *ex quibus mea intersunt* or *ex quibus cupio* or something. I'm not sure if the partitive genitive can be used this way. (This would not be the first time my intuition fails me.)
- Although *solum* can be used as an adverb, I would rather have it agree with *mensam* here (*solam*).

Comment: In this scenario, when referring to quantities of items, if we were talking about 2 pairs of shoes and a single item such as a table, and since Latin has no articles, would it be more natural to phrase it as '...duas soleas et mensam.' or should we still specify a quantity of 'one' for the single item?

Comment: @NeilHibbert You can always use the number for emphasis. It's not used like an article, but when listing amounts, it does make sense to mention "one" explicitly.